# Best handling if data does not pass validation test

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on an excel spreadsheet that runs some critical calculations.

All of the data the user must enter will be on one tab. I am going to build some validation in to check the data entered, to make sure all required fields are filled in and numeric values are within a valid range.

I am trying to determine the best way to handle the calculation of results if invalid data is detected, without making the spreadsheet frustrating to use.

Here is what I have thought of so far.  What do you think would work best? Do any of these sound like they would frustrate the user? Any other ideas that would work well that are not listed?

1. Validate each cell individually as entered.  Not sure this would work for pasted data.
2. Have a data validation button that the user would press to validate the data. Display warnings if invalid data is detected, but still proceed with the computations.
3. Have a data validation button that the user would press to validate the data. Hide results tabs until data passes validation test.
4. Have a data validation button that the user would press to validate the data. Display results sheets no matter what, but make it so that formulas will not recalculate until validation test is passed.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Best is a relative term. What have you tried so far? Have you taken a look at `Data -> Data Tools -> Data Validation`? If yes, why is it not working for you?

Comment: Yes, I have considered the data validation tools, but my one concern about those is that if data is pasted into the columns, the pasted data will not be validated.

Comment: I am cuurently in the design phases, and am going to start building the validation after I determine which method I want to use.

Answer (score 0):

I have another suggestion: conditional formatting.
You can use the `IsNumber()` worksheet function for verifying if the entry is a number or a string, and there are plenty of validations to do for numbers within ranges.

Comment: If the user is frustrated you have failed ... unless he is trying to fake the input.
Validate as of Dominique's answer !!!

Comment: Thanks. I will try this out.